# Создать бесконечно возрастающую дробь

Tags: циклы

Надо посчитать возрастающую дробь: 1/2, 2/3, 3/4 и т.д.

```
def func(a,b):
    list = []
    for h, j in a, b:
        t = float(a/b)
        a+=1
        b+=1
        list.append(t)
```

Хочу применить эту функцию на два списка, один от диапазона 1-10, другой 2-11. Машина функцию такую написать даёт, но на применение пишет: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Я тоже expected 2: ведь по одной цифре на каждом шаге, или нет? Товарищи, как можно довести подсчёт до конца? или есть способ рациональнее? спасибо

Comment: Так покажите вызов функции тоже

Comment: А почему a/b, у вас другие переменные цикла же. Разберитесь с переменными, вы в них запутались

Comment: Что делает этот оператор `for h, j in a, b:`? Нет, не так. Что вы хотели сделать в этом операторе?

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо использовать zip, а в цикле использовать h и j. Функция zip попарно объединяет элементы 2 и более списков в списки:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = [4, 5, 6]
print(list(zip(a1, a2)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Ваша функция:

```
def func(a,b):
    list = []
    for h, j in zip(a, b):
        t = float(h/j)
        ...
```

Это если отвечать на вопрос об ошибке.

Однако вашу задачу, наверное, следует решать как-то иначе. У вас числитель и знаменатель отличаются на 1, стоит этим воспользоваться. Будем задавать перменной `n` номер нашего элемента в последовательности `1/2, 2/3, 3/4`. Например для дроби `3/4` `n` будет равно 3. Общая формула для дроби `n/(n+1)`

```
n = 3
f = n/(n+1)
```

Если вам допустим надо вычислить сумму этих дробей, то

```
n = 10
f_list = [i/(i+1) for i in range(n+1)] 
print(sum(f_list))
```

Output:
`7.980122655122655`